# Trying to setup MQ with a GET message off the queue (not JMS)

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am using the low level direct IBM MQ library to push messages on the queue and retrieve them.  I was trying to setup the application such that messages can come in, say by pulling data of a database and then pushing records onto the queue and actually same code may read messages.  I was mostly wanted to setup a thread that would pull messages once they come up.

This code runs, the first PUT works but the second one does not work and hangs.  Am I not understanding the flow here

Also, if I take the code from the second below around the "GET", could I write a thread that calls that routine every 500 milliseconds, waiting for new messages to come in.

```
        final int putOptions = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT
                    | MQC.MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE;
            this.mqPMO = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            this.mqPMO.options = putOptions;
            // This code hangs !!!! (error here)
            mqueue.put(msg, this.mqPMO);
```

...

```
public void bootstap() {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "localhost";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
        MQEnvironment.channel = "DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN";
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQConstants.APPNAME_PROPERTY, "my_application_name");
        MQEnvironment.enableTracing(5);

        MQQueueManager mqManager = null;
        MQQueue mqueue = null;
        try {
            // MQCNO_CLIENT_BINDING is not available for Java or .NET as they have their own mechanisms for choosing the bind type.
            final String qmName = "QM1";
            final String userId = "admin";
            final String Password = "passw0rd";
            final Hashtable h = new Hashtable();

            h.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userId);
            h.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, Password);
            h.put(MQConstants.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);
            mqManager = new MQQueueManager(qmName, h);
            //mqManager = new MQQueueManager(qmName, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_BINDINGS);
            
            this.mqGMO = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            this.mqGMO.options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT |
                    MQC.MQGMO_WAIT |
                    MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT |
                    MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
            this.mqGMO.matchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
            this.mqGMO.waitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;

            int openOptions =  MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED |
                    MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
            mqueue = mqManager.accessQueue("DEV.QUEUE.1", openOptions);
            logger.info(">> Find connection handle queue manager - " + mqueue);

            {
                final MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
                final String correlId = "0002";
                final String byteArry = this.hexStringToByteArray(correlId);

                logger.info(">>> correlId: " + correlId);
                logger.info(">>> byteArry: " + byteArry);

                msg.correlationId = byteArry.getBytes();
                msg.format = MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING;
                // ... and write some text in UTF8 format
                msg.writeUTF("{{ Hello, World }}}");

                // Use the default put message options...
                // Or: pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE
                final int putOptions = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT
                        | MQC.MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE;
                this.mqPMO = new MQPutMessageOptions();
                this.mqPMO.options = putOptions;

                // put the message //
                mqueue.put(msg, this.mqPMO);
                logger.info(" >>> Continue to get routine");
            }

            {
                // This code works !!! get the message
                MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
                retrievedMessage.correlationId = this.hexStringToByteArray("0001").getBytes();
                mqueue.get(retrievedMessage, this.mqGMO);

                // And prove we have the message by displaying the UTF message text
                String msgText = retrievedMessage.readUTF();
                logger.info("~~~~ The message is: " + msgText);
            }

            {
                final MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
                final String correlId = "0001";
                final String byteArry = this.hexStringToByteArray(correlId);

                logger.info(">>> correlId: " + correlId);
                logger.info(">>> byteArry: " + byteArry);

                msg.correlationId = byteArry.getBytes();
                msg.format = MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING;
                // ... and write some text in UTF8 format
                msg.writeUTF("{{ Hello, World }}}");

                // Use the default put message options...
                // Or: pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE
                final int putOptions = MQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT
                        | MQC.MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE;
                this.mqPMO = new MQPutMessageOptions();
                this.mqPMO.options = putOptions;
                // This code hangs !!!! (error here)
                mqueue.put(msg, this.mqPMO);
            }


            mqueue.close();
            mqManager.disconnect();
        } catch(final Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error at MQ manager", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can certainly move the GET code to another thread. Instead of waiting MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED for messages, you can specify the required timeout for waitInterval and let GET call wait for messages for that interval. The PUT hang is interesting, Are you doing something else? complete code may help.

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ jar files are you using?

Comment: IBM MQ all client:  9.2.2.0

I did try to change the wait and that may have fixed it.  Now I get an error that the queue has been emptied out.  Maybe I will go that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, do NOT use MQEnvironment class as it is not thread safe.  You should be using a Hashtable for MQ connection information.

Secondly, what is with all of the final declarations?  Very odd.

Your code doesn't make any sense.  Here is what I see your code doing:

- Set MQ connection information uses the MQEnvironment class
- Set UserId and Password in a Hashtable
- Connect to the queue manager
- Open the queue
- Set 'correlId' to "0002"

  final String byteArry = this.hexStringToByteArray(correlId);

This line of code does not make any sense.  The method name doesn't match your code.  A Hex string should be in the format of "30303032" for "0002" and return a byte array i.e. byte[] but it is returning a String.  So, I have no idea what the hexStringToByteArray method is doing.

Also, the MsgId, CorrelId and GroupId fields of the MQMD structure are 24 bytes in length.

- Write the message data in a UTF format.  Why?  Does the receiving application require UTF format?
- Put the message on the queue.
- Set the CorrelId for the receive message to "0001" but converted to a strange representation by hexStringToByteArray method.
- Get a message from the queue with a wait interval of unlimited.  Since there is no message on the queue that will match that CorrelId then MQ client library will wait forever!!!!!
- Create another MQMessage and set the CorrelId to "0001" but converted to a strange representation by hexStringToByteArray method.
- Write the message data in a UTF format.  Why?  Does the receiving application require UTF format?
- Put the message on the queue.
- Close the queue
- Disconnect from the queue manager

Here is a fully functioning Java/MQ program that will put 2 messages on a queue with unique CorrelIds (i.e. "0001" & "0002") and then retrieve the message with a  CorrelId of "0002".

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQTest11B
 *
 * Description
 *  This java class will connect to a remote queue manager with the
 *  MQ setting stored in a HashTable, put 2 message on a queue with unique CorrelIds
 *  and then retrieve the message with a  CorrelId of "0002".
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -m MQA1 -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c TEST.CHL -q TEST.Q1 -u UserID -x Password
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix
 */
public class MQTest11B
{
   private static final SimpleDateFormat  LOGGER_TIMESTAMP = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

   private Hashtable<String,String> params;
   private Hashtable<String,Object> mqht;
   private String qMgrName;
   private String outputQName;

   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public MQTest11B()
   {
      super();
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>();
      mqht = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-q") &&
                  params.containsKey("-u") && params.containsKey("-x");
      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ HashTable.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      int port = 1414;
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         qMgrName = (String) params.get("-m");
         outputQName = (String) params.get("-q");

         try
         {
            port = Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            port = 1414;
         }
         
         mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, params.get("-c"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, params.get("-h"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(port));
         mqht.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, params.get("-u"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, params.get("-x"));

         // I don't want to see MQ exceptions at the console.
         MQException.log = null;
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Connect, open queue, write a message, close queue and disconnect.
    *
    */
   private void testSendAndReceive()
   {
      MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
      MQQueue queue = null;
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
      pmo.options = CMQC.MQPMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | CMQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
      gmo.options = CMQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT | CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_CONVERT | CMQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      gmo.matchOptions = CMQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
      gmo.waitInterval = CMQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;
      MQMessage sendmsg;
      String msgData;
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0000");

      try
      {
         qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
         logger("successfully connected to "+ qMgrName);

         queue = qMgr.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions);
         logger("successfully opened "+ outputQName);
         
         /*
          * Code to send 2 messages with a specific CorrelId.  i.e. 0001 and 0002
          */
         for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
         {
            // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text
            sendmsg = new MQMessage();
            sendmsg.format = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            sendmsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
            sendmsg.correlationId = df.format(i+1).getBytes();

            // Write message data
            msgData = "This is a test message from MQTest11B. CorrelID is "+new String(sendmsg.correlationId);
            sendmsg.writeString(msgData);

            // put the message on the queue
            queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
            logger("Sent: Message Data>>>" + msgData);
         }
         
         /*
          * Code to receive a message with a specific CorrelId.  i.e. 0002
          */
         
         // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text
         MQMessage receiveMsg = new MQMessage();
         receiveMsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
         receiveMsg.correlationId = "0002".getBytes();

         // get the message on the queue
         queue.get(receiveMsg, gmo);

         if (CMQC.MQFMT_STRING.equals(receiveMsg.format))
         {
            String msgStr = receiveMsg.readStringOfByteLength(receiveMsg.getMessageLength());
            logger("Received: Message Data>>>" + msgStr);
         }
         else
         {
            byte[] b = new byte[receiveMsg.getMessageLength()];
            receiveMsg.readFully(b);
            logger("Received: Message Data>>>" + new String(b));
         }
      }
      catch (MQException e)
      {
         logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         logger("IOException:" +e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (queue != null)
            {
               queue.close();
               logger("closed: "+ outputQName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
         try
         {
            if (qMgr != null)
            {
               qMgr.disconnect();
               logger("disconnected from "+ qMgrName);
            }
         }
         catch (MQException e)
         {
            logger("CC=" +e.completionCode + " : RC=" + e.reasonCode);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * A simple logger method
    * @param data
    */
   public static void logger(String data)
   {
      String className = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName();

      // Remove the package info.
      if ( (className != null) && (className.lastIndexOf('.') != -1) )
         className = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

      System.out.println(LOGGER_TIMESTAMP.format(new Date())+" "+className+": "+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()+": "+data);
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MQTest11B write = new MQTest11B();

      try
      {
         write.init(args);
         write.testSendAndReceive();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         logger("Usage: java MQTest11B -m QueueManagerName -h host -p port -c channel -q QueueName -u UserID -x Password");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

And the output should look like this:

```
2021/07/02 14:01:59.316 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: successfully connected to MQA1
2021/07/02 14:01:59.332 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: successfully opened TEST.Q1
2021/07/02 14:01:59.332 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: Sent: Message Data>>>This is a test message from MQTest11B. CorrelID is 0001
2021/07/02 14:01:59.347 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: Sent: Message Data>>>This is a test message from MQTest11B. CorrelID is 0002
2021/07/02 14:01:59.347 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: Received: Message Data>>>This is a test message from MQTest11B. CorrelID is 0002
2021/07/02 14:01:59.347 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: closed: TEST.Q1
2021/07/02 14:01:59.347 MQTest11B: testSendAndReceive: disconnected from MQA1
```

Comment: I will try this, how would you change your code such that...I can have a thread that will handle the GET / pull from queue and wait for any messages to come in.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do that but sure, just separate out whatever code you want into a separate class then start the thread.  Note: Each thread MUST have its own connection to the queue manager.  Threads cannot share a connection handle.

Comment: It is not clear in my simple sample.  But imagine a server process and messages will be put onto the queue and we would want a thread to receive any messages that are incoming.

Comment: IBM MQ classes for JMS is better for this with a async message listener. This uses callback at the MQ protocol level. that you are using does not support callback. and it have been stabilized by IBM at the functionality of v7.0.

Comment: Is it possible to get the callbacks with the same correlation id approach above.

Comment: @Roger trying to run something like this.   Sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt. Sometimes hangs on the put or get for 4 minutes and have to exit program.  

https://gist.github.com/berlinbrown/09cc15b4c4904bfbe391374fb663c606

Comment: It is probably a timing issue between the 2 threads (main thread closing queue or connection before child is done).  As I mentioned before, each thread needs its own connection.

Comment: Also, what you are trying to do makes no sense.  If you want to do a get with CorrelId then you should be coding for synchronous processing and not Asynchronous.  If you really, really want to turn request/response into async processing then in the getter thread have it make its own connection and open queue calls and use Java's [Blocking Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/11/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to communicate between the 2 threads.

Comment: @BerlinBrown I've created another MQ/Java application that has a Getter thread for retrieving messages off the queue.  The code is here: https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6628